# Accessing Proto Fields of Underlying Proto Object in Webots

Tags: webots, first-robotics

I'm working on integrating Webots with FIRST Robot Code's builtin simulation utilities. As part of this, I've created a few base protos which define common types of parts, and extended them with common implementations, however, I cannot find a way to access the fields on the base proto from the API. Is there a way to retrieve the base proto node fields from the proto node object?

Example:

Base Proto:

```
#VRML_SIM R2023b utf8
# template language: javascript

# A RotationalMotor with the properties necessary to construct a WPILib DCMotor
PROTO WPIMotorBase [
    unconnectedField SFInt32 port 0
    unconnectedField SFString{"Spark Max", "Talon SRX", "Victor SPX", "PWM"} controllerType "Spark Max"
    field SFFloat gearing 1
    unconnectedField SFBool inverted FALSE
    unconnectedField SFFloat nominalVoltageVolts 12
    field SFFloat stallTorqueNewtonMeters 5
    unconnectedField SFFloat stallCurrentAmps 100
    unconnectedField SFFloat freeCurrentAmps 1
    field SFFloat freeSpeedRPM 5000
    field SFString sound "default"
]
{
    RotationalMotor {
        maxTorque %<= fields.stallTorqueNewtonMeters.value * fields.gearing.value >%
        maxVelocity %<= fields.freeSpeedRPM.value / fields.gearing.value >%
        # The documentation about the multiplier field is unclear as to how it applies differently to differnt fields/functions.
        # I think it's best just to implement it ourselves for now.
        # multiplier %<= 1 / fields.gearing.value >%
        %< if (fields.sound.value !== "default") { >%
            soundUrl IS sound
        %< } >%
    }
}
```

Implementation Proto:

```
#VRML_SIM R2023b utf8

# license: WPILib BSD
# license url: https://github.com/wpilibsuite/allwpilib/blob/main/LICENSE.md

EXTERNPROTO "../protos/WPIMotorBase.proto"

# A WPIMotorBase with the parameters of a NEO motor.
PROTO NEOMotor [
    field SFInt32 id 0
    field SFFloat gearing 1
    field SFBool inverted FALSE
    field SFString sound "default"
]
{
    WPIMotorBase {
        port IS id
        controllerType "Spark Max"
        gearing IS gearing
        inverted IS inverted
        nominalVoltageVolts 12
        stallTorqueNewtonMeters 2.6
        stallCurrentAmps 105
        freeCurrentAmps 1.8
        freeSpeedRPM 5676
        sound IS sound
    }
}
```

Then, adding it to the world tree, and adding the following code to the default Java Controller implementation:

```
        Supervisor robot = new Supervisor();
        Node motor = robot.getFromDevice(robot.getMotor("rotational motor"));
        
        System.out.println("Basic Info");
        System.out.println(motor.getTypeName());
        System.out.println(motor.getParentNode().getTypeName());
        System.out.println(motor.getDef());
        
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Fields");

  
        for(int i = 0; i < motor.getNumberOfFields(); i++) {
            Field field = motor.getFieldByIndex(i);
            System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.getTypeName());
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Proto Fields");
  
        for(int i = 0; i < motor.getProtoNumberOfFields(); i++) {
            Field field = motor.getProtoFieldByIndex(i);
            System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.getTypeName());
        }
```

Prints:

```
Basic Info
NEOMotor
HingeJoint
 
Fields
id: SFInt32
gearing: SFFloat
inverted: SFBool
sound: SFString
 
Proto Fields
name: SFString
acceleration: SFFloat
consumptionFactor: SFFloat
controlPID: SFVec3f
maxVelocity: SFFloat
minPosition: SFFloat
maxPosition: SFFloat
maxTorque: SFFloat
multiplier: SFFloat
sound: SFString
muscles: MFNode
```

So, enumerating the fields retrieves all the fields defined on the specific proto implementation (NEOMotor), and enumerating the proto fields retrieves all the fields defined on the base type (RotationalMotor), but neither returns any of the fields defined on WPIMotorBase. Are these completely inaccessible or is there another method to retrieve a reference to the internal proto?

(Side Question: Isn't this backwards? I would think the proto field getters would get the fields defined on the proto. "If the field is an internal field of a PROTO, the `wb_supervisor_node_get_proto_field` function should be used instead." -Webots Docs)

I've also tried using the DEF structure to retrieve an internal proto def (`DEF internal WPIMotorBase {` and `DEF internal RotationalMotor {`) (not at the same time), and then attempting to access it with `robot.getFromDevice(robot.getMotor("rotational motor")).getFromProtoDef("internal")`, but this just returns null.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that what you want to achieve is not currently possible in Webots. However, I agree that the name of the `wb_supervisor_node_get_proto_field` is misleading. Instead, we should probably remove it and introduce a couple of methods, like wb_supervisor_node_get_proto_parent() which would return the parent class node (or proto node) on which we could query the fields with `wb_supervisor_node_get_field`.

Comment: @olivier-michel Darn! I guess I'll have to go to my backup plan and work around it for now by using name mangling. I've opened an issue in the Webots repository with your suggestions, so this feature request is now tracked at [cyberbots/webots#6354](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/issues/6354). Thanks for the help!